# AWS Amplify #current-cloud-backend duplicate files

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

In my AWS amplify project, the #current-cloud-backend folder that contains the current cloud state of the checked out environment's resources continues to add duplicate files like backend-config 2.json, backend-config 3.json. When I run amplify pull, all of these duplicates, including cloud formation template files, are loaded into my local backend. These duplicates are not allowed when I try to push new backend code.[Example of duplicate files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVQf9.png)

I tried clearing the duplicates and pushing a corrected backend, but running amplify pull or amplify push just brings back the duplicates.